# Test-WSMan fails with powershell

Tags: powershell, rdp

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-WSMan x.x.xx.x
Test-WSMan : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="995" Machine="desktop-12"><f:Message>WS-Management cannot process the request. The operation
failed because of an HTTP error. The HTTP error (12152) is: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response . </f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-WSMan x.x.xx.x
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (x.x.xx.x:String) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.TestWSManCommand
```

I am failing to execute command from this laptop only. RDP connectivity is succeed on this laptop.
Below are output from some commands

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config/service/auth
Auth
    Basic = false
    Kerberos = true
    Negotiate = true
    Certificate = false
    CredSSP = false
    CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetConnectionProfile

Name             : Unidentified network
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 2
InterfaceIndex   : 8
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : NoTraffic
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : K32806
InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
InterfaceIndex   : 17
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts

   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   x.x.xx.x
```

I have enabled Enable-PSRemoting -force, Restart-Service WinRM and tried Test-WSMan but not luck.Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Could be your anti virus is 'protocol filtering'. The error looks a lot like described in [this blog](https://mikefrobbins.com/2012/06/21/welcome-to-powershell-hell/)

Comment: Anti-virus is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your host is accessible from local machine and is not in private network if it is in private vpn connection will required.
2. Verify Host Ip is correct